# How do I go into the Fedora interface window?

Tags: fedora

I restarted Fedora and went into the black login screen.
[image]

How do I go into the interface below?
[image]

Comment: Everyone — in this case, the GUI wasn't _lost_. It was just never there to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal screenshot indicates that you have installed [Fedora Atomic Host](https://getfedora.org/atomic/). This is a container-optimized (server) operating system. It is meant to run in a VM, in a datacenter, or in a cloud provider. Although it is possible to get a GUI desktop environment running on it, that's not what it's really meant for. (We have some effort underway to make an Atomic-like desktop version, but that's a ways off.)

Your best bet is to install the [Fedora Workstation](https://getfedora.org/workstation/), which features the GNOME desktop, or one of our other [desktop spins](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/).

Your other screenshot is from Fedora 11, from 2009. We don't have a desktop environment that looks exactly like that anymore. The closest choice will probably be [MATE Compiz](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/mate-compiz/) — but if it's just that you wanted a GUI desktop rather than a command-line environment, I encourage you to start with Workstation, our main offering. (Or, if that's not to your taste, take a look at the other spins.)

Comment: I have the interface above before restart. After restart it went into black login screen. How do I get it back the interface again?

Comment: @e12345678 Wait, what? That would be... strange. Is it possible you are using random screenshots you found online as examples? Does your screen actually look exactly like these?